# How to handle multiple views in tkinter(python)?

Tags: python, tkinter

### Problem:

Here is my minesweeper game and I want user to login before starting the game. I tried to create a frame with Authentication and it works, but I don't understend how to change view from auth to the game.I dont want you to review game logic, just how to handle screen change.

### Code:

```py
from random import shuffle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3


colors = {
    1: "green",
    2: "dark orange",
    3: "dark blue",
    4: "light blue",
    5: "light braun",
    6: "light green",
    7: "dakr yellow",
    8: "dakr pink",
}


class Authentication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, on_login):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.on_login = on_login

        self.root.title("Authentication")
        self.__authenticated = False

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        # Creating the users table if it doesn't exist
        self.cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, password TEXT)"
        )

        username_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Username:")
        username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        password_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Password:")
        password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        login_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Login", command=self.login)
        login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2, sticky="WE")

        register_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Register", command=self.register)
        register_button.grid(
            row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2, sticky="WE"
        )

    def login(self):
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        self.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?", (username, password)
        )

        if self.cursor.fetchone():
            self.__authenticated = True
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login successful!")
            self.on_login()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Failure", "Invalid username or password!")

        self.username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def register(self):
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", (username,))

        if self.cursor.fetchone():
            messagebox.showerror("Failure", "Username already exists!")
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)",
                (username, password),
            )
            self.conn.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Registration successful!")

        self.username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.__authenticated


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y, number=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, width=5, font="Calibri 15 bold", *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.number = number
        self.is_mine = False
        self.count_bomb = 0
        self.is_open = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyButton{self.x} {self.y} {self.number} {self.is_mine}"


class MineSweeper:
    ROW = 9
    COLUMNS = 9
    MINES = 10
    IS_GAME_OVER = False
    IS_FIRST_CLICK = True

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.buttons = []
        self.authentication = Authentication(root, on_login=self.start_game)
        for i in range(MineSweeper.ROW + 2):
            temp = []
            for j in range(MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 2):
                btn = MyButton(root, x=i, y=j)
                btn.config(command=lambda button=btn: self.click(button))
                btn.bind("<Button-3>", self.right_click)
                temp.append(btn)
            self.buttons.append(temp)

    def right_click(self, event):
        if MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER:
            return
        cur_btn = event.widget
        if cur_btn["state"] == "normal":
            cur_btn["state"] = "disabled"
            cur_btn["text"] = ""
            cur_btn["disabledforeground"] = "dark red"
        elif cur_btn["text"] == "":
            cur_btn["text"] = ""
            cur_btn["state"] = "normal"

    def click(self, clicked_button: MyButton):
        if MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER:
            return

        if MineSweeper.IS_FIRST_CLICK:
            self.insert_mines(clicked_button.number)
            self.count_mines_in_buttons()
            self.print_buttons()
            MineSweeper.IS_FIRST_CLICK = False

        if clicked_button.is_mine:
            clicked_button.config(
                text="*", background="red", disabledforeground="black"
            )
            clicked_button.is_open = True
            MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER = True
            messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Ви програли")
            for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
                for j in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
                    btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                    if btn.is_mine:
                        btn["text"] = "*"
        else:
            color = colors.get(clicked_button.count_bomb, "black")
            if clicked_button.count_bomb:
                clicked_button.config(
                    text=clicked_button.count_bomb, disabledforeground=color
                )
                clicked_button.is_open = True
            else:
                self.breadth_first_search(clicked_button)

            clicked_button.config(state="disabled")
            clicked_button.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN)

            # check if the player won the game
            no_of_closed_buttons = 0
            for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
                for j in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
                    if not self.buttons[i][j].is_open:
                        no_of_closed_buttons += 1
            if no_of_closed_buttons == MineSweeper.MINES:
                MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER = True
                messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations", "Ви виграли!")

    def breadth_first_search(self, btn: MyButton):
        queue = [btn]
        while queue:
            cur_btn = queue.pop()
            color = colors.get(cur_btn.count_bomb, "black")
            if cur_btn.count_bomb:
                cur_btn.config(text=cur_btn.count_bomb, disabledforeground=color)
            else:
                cur_btn.config(text="", disabledforeground=color)
            cur_btn.is_open = True
            cur_btn.config(state="disabled")
            cur_btn.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN)

            if cur_btn.count_bomb == 0:
                x, y = cur_btn.x, cur_btn.y
                for dx in [-1, 0, 1]:
                    for dy in [-1, 0, 1]:
                        # if not abs(dx - dy) == 1:
                        #   continue

                        next_btn = self.buttons[x + dx][y + dy]
                        if (
                            not next_btn.is_open
                            and 1 <= next_btn.x <= MineSweeper.ROW
                            and 1 <= next_btn.y <= MineSweeper.COLUMNS
                            and next_btn not in queue
                        ):
                            queue.append(next_btn)

    def reload(self):
        for child in self.root.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
        self.__init__(self.root)
        self.create_widgets()
        MineSweeper.IS_FIRST_CLICK = True
        MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER = False

    def create_settings_win(self):
        win_settings = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        win_settings.wm_title("Налаштування")
        tk.Label(win_settings, text="Кількість рядків").grid(row=0, column=0)
        row_entry = tk.Entry(win_settings)
        row_entry.insert(0, MineSweeper.ROW)
        row_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        tk.Label(win_settings, text="Кількість колонок").grid(row=1, column=0)
        column_entry = tk.Entry(win_settings)
        column_entry.insert(0, MineSweeper.COLUMNS)
        column_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        tk.Label(win_settings, text="Кількість мін").grid(row=2, column=0)
        mines_entry = tk.Entry(win_settings)
        mines_entry.insert(0, MineSweeper.MINES)
        mines_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        save_btn = tk.Button(
            win_settings,
            text="Застосувати",
            command=lambda: self.change_settings(row_entry, column_entry, mines_entry),
        )
        save_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20)

    def change_settings(self, row: tk.Entry, colomn: tk.Entry, mines: tk.Entry):
        try:
            int(row.get()), int(colomn.get()), int(mines.get())
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Помилка", "Ви ввели неправильне значення")
            return

        MineSweeper.ROW = int(row.get())
        MineSweeper.COLUMNS = int(colomn.get())
        MineSweeper.MINES = int(mines.get())
        self.reload()

    def create_widgets(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)

        settings_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        settings_menu.add_command(label="Почати", command=self.reload)
        settings_menu.add_command(
            label="Налаштування", command=self.create_settings_win
        )
        settings_menu.add_command(label="Вийти", command=self.root.destroy)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=settings_menu)

        count = 1
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                btn.number = count
                btn.grid(row=i, column=j, stick="NWES")
                count += 1

        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
            tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, i, weight=1)

        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
            tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, i, weight=1)

    def open_all_buttons(self):
        for i in range(MineSweeper.ROW + 2):
            for j in range(MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 2):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if btn.is_mine:
                    btn.config(text="*", background="red", disabledforeground="black")
                elif btn.count_bomb in colors:
                    color = colors.get(btn.count_bomb, "black")
                    btn.config(text=btn.count_bomb, fg=color)

    def start_game(self):
        self.authentication.destroy()

        self.create_widgets()

    def start(self):
        self.authentication.tkraise()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def print_buttons(self):
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if btn.is_mine:
                    print("B", end=" ")
                else:
                    print(btn.count_bomb, end=" ")
            print()

    def insert_mines(self, number: int):
        index_mines = self.get_mines_places(number)
        print(index_mines)
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if btn.number in index_mines:
                    btn.is_mine = True

    def count_mines_in_buttons(self):
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.ROW + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                count_bomb = 0
                if not btn.is_mine:
                    for row_dx in [-1, 0, 1]:
                        for col_dx in [-1, 0, 1]:
                            neighbour = self.buttons[i + row_dx][j + col_dx]
                            if neighbour.is_mine:
                                count_bomb += 1
                btn.count_bomb = count_bomb

    @staticmethod
    def get_mines_places(exclude_number: int):
        indexes = list(range(1, MineSweeper.COLUMNS * MineSweeper.ROW + 1))
        print(f"Виключаємо кнопку номер {exclude_number}")
        indexes.remove(exclude_number)
        shuffle(indexes)
        return indexes[: MineSweeper.MINES]


root = tk.Tk()

game = MineSweeper(root)
game.start()
```

### Screenshots:

[auth view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXU00.png)
[game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oH8i.png)

- I have tried to use `.destroy` on auth screen (nothing was happening)
- loop through `self.authentication.winfo_children()` and use `.destroy` (got an exception and auth screen didn't change)

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\realn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\realn\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\MineSweeper3.py", line 67, in login
    self.on_login()
  File "c:\Users\realn\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\MineSweeper3.py", line 297, in start_game
    for widget in self.authentication.winfo_children():
  File "C:\Users\realn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1079, in winfo_children
    self.tk.call('winfo', 'children', self._w)):
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!authentication"
```

- loop through `self.winfo_children()` and use `.destroy` (same as previous)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the parent of widgets inside `Authentication` to the frame instead of `root`:

```py
class Authentication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, on_login):
        super().__init__(root)
        ...

        # use self instead of self.root as the parent
        username_label = tk.Label(self, text="Username:")
        ...

        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        ...

        password_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        ...

        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        ...

        login_button = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        ...

        register_button = tk.Button(self, text="Register", command=self.register)
        ...
```

and call a layout function on instance of `Authentication` (otherwise it is hidden):

```py
class MineSweeper:
    ...
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.authentication = Authentication(root, on_login=self.start_game)
        self.authentication.pack() # call a layout manager function
        ...
    ...
```

Also you need to call `return` after `self.on_login()` inside `login()`:

```py
def login(self):
    ...
    if self.cursor.fetchone():
        ...
        self.on_login()
        return    # exit function
    else:
        ...
    ...
```